# Mandar parametros GET para um php usando o comando exec

Tags: php, exec

Estou tentando mandar parametros GET para um php usando o comando exec do php, mas quando coloco os parametros o script não roda, ele não chega até o outro php, segue meu código:

*exec.php:*

```
$cmd = 'php teste.php?id=10,11';
$pid = exec($cmd.' > /dev/null &');
```

*teste.php:*

```
$ids = $_GET["id"];
echo $ids;
```

Não recebo msgs de erro.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pelo que vejo, você está tentando passar um argumento para o script PHP que é executado na linha de comando.

Em linha de comando, não se usa `$_GET` para acessar argumentos de um script. Você deve usar a variável `$argv` para acessar esses argumentos.

## Passando e acessando os argumentos

Crie um arquivo `cmd.php`, faça o seguinte:

```
print_r($argv);
```

Execute na linha de comando:

```
>>> php cmd.php 1 2 3
```

O resultado será:

```
Array
(
    [0] => cmd.php
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
)
```

Note que o primeiro argumento do `$argv` é o nome do script em execução. Isso é sempre assim.

Se você quer obter apenas os argumentos depois do script, você pode usar `array_slice`, assim:

```
print_r(array_slice($argv, 1))
```

Quando você executa um `script` php via linha de comando, cada item separado por um espaço depois de `php` é considerado um argumento do comando.

Ou seja, você não vai usar a interrogação `?` como você faz no caso das query strings do navegador.

**Mas e se eu quiser passar um argumento que tenha espaço?**

Se você quiser passar um argumento que contenha um espaço literal, você pode usar as aspas para delimitar o argumento.

Assim:

```
>>> php cmd.php "olá mundo"
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => cmd.php
    [1] => olá mundo
)
```

**E se eu quiser passar a aspas como argumento?**

Aí você tem que escapar com a `\`.

Exemplo:

```
>>> php cmd.php "olá \""
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => cmd.php
    [1] => olá "
)
```

E antes que me pergunte "Como escapar a barra também", eu adianto que é só usar outra barra.

Exemplo:

```
  >>> php cmd.php \\My\\Namespace
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [0] => cmd.php
    [1] => \My\Namespace
)
```

## Contagem de argumentos passados

Para contar o número de argumentos, você pode usar também a variável `$argc`.

Crie um arquivo `count_args.php` para testar e coloque o seguinte:

```
  print_r($argc)
```

Execute na linha de comando:

```
 >>> php count_args.php 1 2 3 4
```

O resultado será:

```
5
```

Nada impede também de você usar `count($argv)` para contar os argumentos.

Comment: obrigado, consegui!